# Building an R package which could run on any hardware

Tags: r, windows, macos

I have been building an R package for some inequality index. It also contains some C code. I use windows 7 so I have put the .dll file in an src folder. How to make sure that it runs perfectly on any type of hardware? Do I need to upload the .so file for MAC OS users?

Comment: "...so I have put the .dll file in an src folder." No, no, no. Just no. You put *source* code in src/. And you should not be distributing binaries.  Include the source code and users can build the binaries themselves.

Comment: So at the time of package submission, I will just provide the source code in the src/. Nothing extra?

Comment: Yes. CRAN will reject your submission if you include binaries.  It's in their policy, which I *strongly* suggest you read very carefully before submitting.

Comment: you should also carefully read the relevant sections of the [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) manual ...